# Calculate Euclidean distance like ArcGIS does using PyQGIS

Tags: raster, pyqgis

I want to build a plugin like to calculate Euclidean distance like ArcGIS, or are there any existing plugins?

[image: Euclidean distance]

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Proximity tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasteranalysis.html?highlight=proximity#proximity-raster-distance) in the Processing Toolbox | GDAL | Raster Analysis:

> **Proximity (raster distance)**
>
> Generates a raster proximity map indicating the distance from the center of each pixel to the center of the nearest pixel identified as a target pixel. Target pixels are those in the source raster for which the raster pixel value is in the set of target pixel values.

[image]

Comment: but i have an study task, i have to realize a Features like this in qgis plugin throwing pyqgis , so is there any tutorials or code can i refer？

Comment: You can run processing tools from python, i.e you can include a call to the Proximity tool in your plugin https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html